# Multithreading array processing and then writing to result array for C-Python extension

Tags: python, c, multithreading, openmp

The code below is a C-Python extension. This code takes an input **buffer** of contiguous raw bytes (for my application, "blocks" of raw bytes, where 1 block = 128 bytes) and then processes these bytes into 2 byte "samples" putting the result into **items**. The returned structure is just the buffer processed into python integers.

Here are the 2 main functions:

*unpack_block(items, items_offset, buffer, buffer_offset, samples_per_block, sample_bits);*

A loop then goes through each sample in **items** and then transforms each sample into a Python Int.

*PyList_SET_ITEM(result, index, PyInt_FromLong( items[index] ));*

```
    unsigned int num_blocks_per_thread, num_samples_per_thread, num_bytes_per_thread;
    unsigned int thread_id, p;
    unsigned int n_threads, start_index_bytes, start_index_blocks, start_index_samples;

    items = malloc(num_samples*sizeof(unsigned long));
    assert(items);

    #pragma omp parallel\
    default(none)\
    private(num_blocks_per_thread, num_samples_per_thread, num_bytes_per_thread, d, j, thread_id, n_threads, start_index_bytes, start_index_blocks, start_index_samples)\
    shared(samples_per_block, num_blocks, buffer, bytes_per_block, sample_bits, result, num_samples, items)
      {

        n_threads = omp_get_num_threads();
        num_blocks_per_thread = num_blocks/n_threads;
        num_samples_per_thread = num_samples/n_threads; 
        num_bytes_per_thread = num_blocks_per_thread*samples_per_block*2/n_threads;

        thread_id = omp_get_thread_num();
        start_index_bytes = num_bytes_per_thread*thread_id;
        start_index_blocks = num_blocks_per_thread*thread_id;  
        start_index_samples = num_samples_per_thread*thread_id;

        for (d=0; d<num_blocks_per_thread; d++) {
          unpack_block(items, start_index_samples+d*samples_per_block, buffer, start_index_blocks + d*bytes_per_block, samples_per_block, sample_bits);
        }

      }

     result = PyList_New(num_samples);
     assert(result);

     //*THIS WOULD ALSO SEEM RIPE FOR MULTITHREADING*
     for (p=0; p<num_samples; p++) {
        PyList_SET_ITEM(result, p, PyInt_FromLong( items[p] ));
      }

    free(items);
    free(buffer);

  return result;
}
```

The speed is just atrocious and far less than what I expect from multi-threading. I may have a false-sharing problem going on with the threads writing to different chunks of the **items** array, even though each thread only processes a mutually-exclusive chunk of the same array.

A fundamental question for me would be: how to correctly multi-thread the per-element processing of a single array, and then output the result per-element into a second "result" array. I perform this twice with my two functions.

Any ideas, solutions, or ways to optimize would be great. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You already mention false sharing. In order to avoid it, you have to allocate the memory accordingly (using posix_memalign or another aligned alloc function) and also choose the chunk size so that the data size of one chunk is an exact multiple of the cache line size.

Generally, measure the execution time using $N$ threads and calculate the speedup. Can you share the speedup curve with us?

As to the comment "This would seem ripe for multi-threading": Often, the expectations are too high (just as a word of warning to avoid disappointment). Consider how many threads/elements per thread you use and what the workload per thread (i.e., how many computations are required per item) is. Maybe the workload is so small that the OpenMP overhead dominates. Additionally, how many instructions are required per memory load operation? Typically, many instructions per memory load are reasonable candidates to parallelize. A low ratio indicates that the program is memory bound.

Speaking of memory access, are you on a multi-socket system with different NUMA domains? If yes, you have to take care of affinity issues.